# Can't sum values in Angularjs if one value is an empty string

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, steroids

I am building a simple Appgyver mobile app using Angularjs and Coffeescript - I'm a beginner with both of these.

I wish to determine the total cost for a list of up to 20 items stored on the database. However, there may be less than 20 items.

I have attempted to do the calculation with ng-bind, which works perfectly as long as all strings contain values. However, if there are less than 20 pairs (values go up to q20 and p20) then the calculation returns NaN.

I would like to determine the total of all existing values for the list. I have looked at numerous examples on stackoverflow, Angularjs.org and other sites and have experimented with a myriad of alternative methods, however I think I lack the basic understanding of how to make this work. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I have used, shortened to 3 pairs instead of 20:

```
 <span ng-bind="client['q1'].price * client['p1'].price + client['q2'].price 
* client['p2'].price + client['q3'].price * client['p3'].price"></span>
```

This is the existing controller:

```
angular
  .module('client')
  .controller("ShowController", ($scope, Client, supersonic) ->
$scope.client = 0;
$scope.showSpinner = true
$scope.dataId = undefined


_refreshViewData = ->
  Client.find($scope.dataId).then (client) ->
    $scope.$apply ->
      $scope.client = client
      $scope.showSpinner = false


supersonic.ui.views.current.whenVisible ->
  _refreshViewData() if $scope.dataId

supersonic.ui.views.current.params.onValue (values) ->
  $scope.dataId = values.id
  _refreshViewData()

$scope.remove = (id) ->
  $scope.showSpinner = true
  $scope.client.delete().then ->
    supersonic.ui.layers.pop()
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overloading (in the linguistic sense, not the coding sense) `ng-bind`. Doing all of that code in your HTML is messy and is not what it was created for. You would be better off doing the math in your controller, and then referencing it in ng-bind. You have only 3 pairs here, but you say you have 20, and could be more, so do it that way:

```
<span ng-bind="totalPrice"></span>
```

And in your controller:

```
  var setTotalPrice = function() {
    var ret = 0, i, maxClient = 6, client = $scope.client; // or however else you keep track of them
    for (i=1;i<=maxClient;i++) {
      if (client['q'+i] && client['q'+i].price && !isNaN(client['q'+i].price) &&
          client['p'+i] && client['p'+i].price && !isNaN(client['p'+i].price)) {
         ret += (client['q'+i].price * client['p'+i].price);
     }
  }
  $scope.totalPrice = ret;
};
$scope.setTotalPrice = setTotalPrice;
setTotalPrice();
```

Just call `setTotalPrice` in your controller whenever you want, or on an `ng-click`.

Comment: Thanks Deitch, I have created a new controller with js for this - not coffeescript, and it returns 0. I've spent a few hours trying to get this to work and the only value it will return is whatever var ret =, in this case 0.

Comment: Throw up a fiddle or plunkr for it, happy to look. Here is a basic angular jsfiddle with all of the libs included so you can just do your html and controllers/services/directives/filters. http://jsfiddle.net/o2oxuz12/

Comment: I haven't fiddled before so may have missed something. I have tried to recreate the data that is on Built IO: https://jsfiddle.net/o2oxuz12/1/

Comment: Try this. There were some errors, and client was on scope but accessed as local var in the fn, etc. https://jsfiddle.net/o2oxuz12/3/

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly in the Fiddle but breaks my app for some reason! Now I can work on a new problem! If you can change the code in the answer to the code that you corrected in the Fiddle I can accept your answer. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't abuse `ng-bind` for calculations! Instead calculate the values in your controller and bind the resulting value.

Problem with your code is -if any of the values is not a number your result becomes `NaN`. In the controller function you check for the presence of value and then operate. You may want to check whether the value is non-null as well as a number string and then operate on it.